# Interface Inheritance differences

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've got the following code

```
interface IColourable
{ 
    Color Color { get; set; }
}

interface IDrawable : IColourable
{
    void Draw(int length);
    Color Color { get; set; }
}

class Square : IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(int length)
    { ... }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to know if there is difference between those classes, and if there's a difference, when should I use the first and when the second case?

```
class Square : IDrawable, IColourable
{
    public void Draw(int length)
    { ... }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: go with the first (don't think there is a difference) - but your *casing*  of names is really strange why not `IDrawable` and `Color Color {get;set;}`, ...?

Comment: The first is recommended. I have on occasion encountered complications when having accidentally done the second - which complications caused me to notice the oversight. Details escape me at this moment.

Comment: hahaha, because I wrote this example to explain interfaces in my documentation. `Color Color` not to mess up types with names, but I agree `draw` should be  `Draw`

Comment: then think of another name - it's really bad practice to mix up conventions in that way ;)

Comment: It makes no difference.  Microsoft routinely repeats inherited interfaces in framework code, it is very good for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second class has a redundant declaration, since IDrawable already inherits from IColourable.
Practically, there is no difference between the two classes.